# How do you add buses to a small bus terminal?

Tags: cities-xl

I have a small bus terminal that allows me to have up to three bus lines.

When I built it, it allowed me to get my first bus line in, but now I want to add a second one. When I click "Bus line management", it doesn't have an "Add bus line" link or anything like that.

Does anyone know how to add a bus line?

Comment: ...minecraft tag?

Comment: there was a problem with me posting it with only the cities xl tag, so i tried 2 tags. and then editing it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Taken from the [Cities-XL forums](http://forum.citiesxl.com/viewtopic.php?t=182&f=16):

> How do I create a new bus line?
>
> Go to the construction menu, click on
> the terminus and place it. You can
> create your first bus line straight
> after placing the terminal.
>
> If you wish to create another line
> later, you will need to go back to the
> construction menu and click on the
> terminus’ icon again. Then click on
> the terminus already placed and start
> placing the stops for your new line.